# Can you have both maven's and gradle in same java build?

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle, netbeans

We already started our project in mavens(spring mvc) but realized gradle is better for managing big to enterprise level builds like our project.  Is there a way to keep mavens but also add on gradle to the same build?

And if yes, how would I add gradle to my existing maven project?  thanks.

Comment: Short answer: **yes**. There's no conflict between having two independent build scripts for the same project, one in Maven and one in Gradle.

Comment: @ericbn - thanks.  Can you link any tutorials or possibly answer how I can add gradle to my existing maven project via netbeans?

Comment: Running `gradle init` will help you generate gradle files from Maven's pom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to make a decision:

- Invoke maven from gradle
- Invoke gradle from maven

If your end goal is to move to gradle then I suggest invoking maven from gradle. It looks like there's a plugin [here](https://github.com/dkorotych/gradle-maven-exec-plugin) which will do the job

Comment: thanks for answer.  Curios, which do you personally prefer maven or gradle? Main reasons why?

Comment: No competition, Gradle wins hands down. I've even written a [plugin to help move from maven to gradle](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-maven-share). Maven is far too rigid for me and hard to do custom stuff. Gradle starts with mavens sensible conventions but adding custom logic is simple. Writing a maven plugin is difficult and you'd rarely attempt it. Writing a Gradle plugin is simple and cleans up your build so it's a common thing to do

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I had a grumpy about this while trying to email, and then having to re-edit for tone multiple times, some potential deal breakers I wanted a hiring manager to look at for a position involving a Java backend recently and googled to advise/vent.

My three career-worst experiences in 15+ years as a front end web developer with plenty of back end exposure has been with Java teams and Java build processes that used Ant, Maven, AND Gradle. Builds were absurdly brittle, often breaking with no config or even back end changes made, and there were three sets of config, docs, and sources of errors to look at when anything went wrong.

In all three cases, getting help from Java dev team members after making reasonable attempts to diagnose myself was like pulling teeth because they often couldn't diagnose without trivial effort either and they didn't want to miss THEIR sprint goals.

For the love of sanity, think about the actual problem a dependency manager solves and then don't give your dependencies 2-3 bosses. No matter how quickly and smoothly it solves your problem in the short term, stuff goes stale eventually, often in the most annoying parts of a dependency chain possible, and then you've got a potential hot mess nobody wants to clean up. Upgrade all the way or not at all.